# ¿Como puedo agregarle a esta expresion regular que me permita introducir dos puntos consecutivos despues del @?

Tags: javascript, regex

Esta es la expresión regular que estoy usando para validar un correo.

Funciona, considera que es valido por ejemplo este correo (correo@gmail.com), pero necesito que reconozca también que es valido si ingreso de esta manera(correo@gmail.com.py), no entiendo la manera de agregarle para que me reconozca el .py despues del @..Gracias de antemano.

```
/^[-\w.%+]{2,64}@(?:[A-Z0-9-]{1,63}\.){1,125}{2,63}[.]{2} $/i;
```

Comment: Esa expresión regular está mal. ¿A qué se refiere el `{2,63}`? Falta un item válido delante

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No necesitas una expresión tan larga para validar un email, originalmente podemos usar esta

```
[^\s*].*[^\s*]\@[a-zA-Z]{2,}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}
```

Donde

- Los signos `.*` hacen match a **cualquier** cosa
- Los signos `[^...]` son **negación**, y **niegan** matches con un criterio específico
- Finalmente, usamos el selector de rango `[a-zA-Z]{2,}` para especificar la extensión de dominio que al menos debe contener dos letras
- Los signos `\s*` son para detectar espacios en blanco

---

Como quieres validar dominios con dos extensiones como señalas tú `.com.py`, podríamos usar el "combinador" de expresiones regulares, para añadirle esta expresión

```
[^\s*].*[^\s*]\@[a-zA-z]{2,}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}
```

Tiene las mismas reglas que el anterior, lo que se añade es `\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}` lo que hace que soporte una extensión más a partir del segundo punto

**Expresión final**

```
[^\s*].*[^\s*]\@[a-zA-Z]{2,}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}|[^\s*].*[^\s*]\@[a-zA-Z]{2,}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}
```

Aquí usamos el "combinador" de expresiones, el cual es `|`, sirve para "combinar" dos expresiones en una y que podamos hacer match con las dos

---

**DEMO**

```js
const r = /[^\s*].*[^\s*]\@[a-zA-Z]{2,}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}|[^\s*].*[^\s*]\@[a-zA-Z]{2,}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}/;
console.log(r.test("correo@gmail.com")); // true
console.log(r.test("correo@gmail.com.py")); // true
console.log(r.test("correo@gmail.c")); // false
console.log(r.test("correo@gmail")); // false
```